# Error code ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE - Can't connect mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database-connection

I created a database in MySQL and wanted to connect it with JS. Below is the code I wrote for that but I got an error.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'********',
    database:'EmployeeDB'
});

mysqlConnection.connect((err) => {
    if (!err)
        console.log('DB Connection Succeded');
    else
        console.log('DB Connection Failed \n Error :'+ JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
});
```

I tried to change the name of the host, and revoke and grant privileges (couldn't do either). Delete and recreate the databse and tried the connection again. I was expected to connect with my database but it resulted in an error that I am unable to understand. The error message is as follows:

```
DB Connection Failed
 Error :{
  "code": "ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE",
  "errno": 1251,
  "sqlMessage": "Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client",
  "sqlState": "08004",
  "fatal": true
}
```

After changing the hostname:

```
DB Connection Failed
 Error :{
  "code": "ER_HOST_NOT_PRIVILEGED",
  "errno": 1130,
  "sqlMessage": "Host 'Mistycyrus.bbrouter' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server",
  "fatal": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first error "Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client" you need to :

1. Make sure your DLL file "libmySQL.dll" is up to date.
2. Maybe your account was created using "Old Authentication Protocol Passwords" while server is using "New Authentication Protocol Passwords" now. for information look at [documentaion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-secure-auth.html).

For the second error "Host 'Mistycyrus.bbrouter' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server", you are connecting using user `'someone'@'Mistycyrus.bbrouter'` and this user is not permitted to connect.

1. According to the word **bbrouter**, it may be something related to your router as I have seen something simmilar with Thomson router before.
2. Check your hosts file. Make sure hosts file contains the line `127.0.0.1 localhost`.